# How to remove continue btn from stepper in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[image: stepper issue screen shot here]

I want to create a delivery status flow to check user product details.
When I write stepper to show this flow there are also continue and cancel buttons on the page but I want to remove these things.

Please help me, I am new in flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Stepper widget has a **controlsBuilder** parameter which is what you need.

```dart
Stepper(
      controlsBuilder: (context, {onStepContinue, onStepCancel}) {
        return SizedBox();
      },
      ...
    )
```

If you check the comments inside the Stepper class source files, you can find more examples of how to control it:

```dart
Stepper(
        controlsBuilder: (context, {onStepContinue, onStepCancel}) {
          return Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: onStepContinue,
                child: const Text('NEXT'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: onStepCancel,
                child: const Text('CANCEL'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        },
        ...
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

i face same problem in stepper where i need to remove continue and cancel button from stepper widget in flutter

i do this way

```
Stepper(
 controlsBuilder: (context, controller) {
                  return const SizedBox.shrink();
                },
),
```

by this you remove space occupied by continue and cancel button

may be you will like whole code

Note : here i used horizonal stepper so i was wraped into  SizeBox and give fixed height for remove unbounded error.

```
class MyCustomSteep extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyCustomSteep({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyCustomSteep> createState() => _MyCustomSteepState();
}

class _MyCustomSteepState extends State<MyCustomSteep> {
  int currentStep = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 110,
      child: Stepper(
        controlsBuilder: (context, controller) {
          return const SizedBox.shrink();
        },
        type: StepperType.horizontal,
        currentStep: currentStep,
        onStepTapped: (stepIndex) {
          setState(() => currentStep = stepIndex);
          log('currentStep : $currentStep');
        },
        elevation: 1.0,
        steps: <Step>[
          Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 0,
            title: const Text(
              'Created',
            ),
            content: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            label: SizedBox(
              height: 80,
              child: Text(
                DateFormat('dd MMM hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 1,
            title: const Text(
              'In Progress',
            ),
            content: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            label: Column(
              children: [
                Text(
                  DateFormat('dd MMM hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 2,
            title: const Text(
              'Vehicle Ready',
            ),
            content: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            label: Text(
              DateFormat('dd MMM hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
            ),
          ),
          Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 3,
            title: const Text(
              'Payment Due',
            ),
            content: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            label: Text(
              DateFormat('dd MMM hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
            ),
          ),
          Step(
            isActive: currentStep >= 4,
            title: const Text(
              'Payment Done',
            ),
            content: const SizedBox.shrink(),
            label: Text(
              DateFormat('dd MMM hh:mm:ss').format(DateTime.now()),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Stepper]

Answer (score 1):

On Above answers, The Stepper on Vertical axis will cause the stepper line to shrink to centre.
So to avoid that. You should use Row.

Also if you want to Avoid space caused by this change, use
margin: EdgeInsets.zero,

```
margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
controlsBuilder: (context, controller) => Row(children: []);
```

Answer (score 0):

return Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
children: [
ElevatedButton(
onPressed: controls.onStepContinue,

```
                child: Text(isLastStep ? 'Submit' : 'Next'),
              ),
              if (_currentStep != 0)

                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: controls.onStepCancel,
                  child: const Text('Back'),
                ),
            ],
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

Stepper widget has a controlsBuilder parameter which can be used.

```
 controlsBuilder: (context, {onStepContinue, onStepCancel}) {
                return Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(),
                    Container(),
                  ],
                );
              }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for flutter version > 2.8.1**

In flutter version > 2.8.1 you can not use this:

```
 controlsBuilder: (context, {onStepContinue, onStepCancel}) {...}
```

Use this:

```
 controlsBuilder: (context, _) {...}
```

Or this:

```
 controlsBuilder: (context, onStepContinue) {...}


 controlsBuilder: (context, onStepCancel) {...}
```

This is a complete example:

```
Stepper(
  controlsBuilder: (context, _) {
    return Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text(
            'NEXT',
            style:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
        TextButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: const Text(
            'EXIT',
            style:
              TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
  //Rest of the Stepper code (currentStep, onStepCancel, onStepContinue, steps...)
  //...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Stepper widget **auto-implements** the property also other already told you: `controlsBuilder`. 
If you want to remove those controls you have just to override that propery passing another function which return a `SizedBox` as @Thepeanut already suggested.

I would just add that you should explicit the height and the width equal to 0.
As here I write:

```
controlsBuilder: (context, details) {
 return const SizedBox(
  height: 0,
  width: 0,
 );
},
```

And the implementation of the methods in `details` it's down here:

```
currentStep: _index,
onStepCancel: () {
 if (_index > 0) {
  setState(() {
   _index -= 1;
  });
 }
},
onStepContinue: () {
 if (_index <= (stepList.length - 2)) {
  setState(() {
   _index += 1;
  });
 }
},
onStepTapped: (int index) {
 setState(() {
  _index = index;
 });
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                    Stepper(
                            steps: steps,
                            
                            controlsBuilder: (context, controller){
                              return SizedBox.shrink();
                            },
                          )
```

You can add this in your controlBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You can use Control builder function to hide the continue and cancel button from stepper.

```
controlsBuilder: (ctx, details) {
                          return Container();
                        },
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8Fgt.png)